# Remove terms from the list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
l = {{-5, -5, -5}, {-7, -5, -1}, {-9, -3, 15}, {-11, 1, 49}, {-13, 7, 0},
{-15, 15, 0}, {-17, 25, 0}, {-19, 37, 0}, {-21, 51, 0}, {-23, 67, 0}, {-25, 85, 0}}
```

I need to remove the items in the list that contain zero in the third item value. Finally I wish to obtain the following list:

`{{-5, -5, -5}, {-7, -5, -1}, {-9, -3, 15}, {-11, 1, 49}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
l = {{-5, -5, -5}, {-7, -5, -1}, {-9, -3, 15}, {-11, 1, 49}, {-13, 7, 
0}, {-15, 15, 0}, {-17, 25, 0}, {-19, 37, 0}, {-21, 51, 0}, {-23, 
67, 0}, {-25, 85, 0}};

DeleteCases[l, {a_, b_, c_} /; c == 0]
```

Comment: Simpler is `DeleteCases[l, {_, _, 0}]`

Comment: It depends if you want to check for exact zeroes (`0`) only or if you want to catch machine precision zeroes as well (`0.`)

Comment: Or with  `Cases[l, {a_, b_, c_} /; c != 0]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Select[l, #[[3]] != 0 &]
```

> {{-5, -5, -5}, {-7, -5, -1}, {-9, -3, 15}, {-11, 1, 49}}

Answer (score 1):

this should be quite fast:

```
Pick[l, Unitize@l[[All, -1]], 1]

(* {{-5, -5, -5}, {-7, -5, -1}, {-9, -3, 15}, {-11, 1, 49}} *)
```